# Using findmin() in data from array composed of mutable struct elements - Julia

Tags: arrays, methods, struct, julia, mutable

Suppose I have the following struct:

```
mutable struct Car
    load
    locale
    availability
    odometer
end
```

And I have created an array:

```
fleet = Vector{Car}(undef, num_cars)

for i in 1:num_cars
   a, b, c, d = rand(4)
   fleet[i] = Car(a, b, c, d)
end
```

How can I find the smallest (with [`findmin`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.findmin) or similar) or biggest (with?) value from, for example, the odometer of all the cars in my array?

Basically, I want to be able to use conditional statements with struct arrays, e.g.: For every element in my struct array, get the ones that a data satisfy a condition and, from those, get the minimum value of another data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding the minimum value is pretty straightforward, using the `minimum` function, with a mapping argument:

```
julia> minimum(x->x.odometer, fleet)
0.08468003971220694
```

If you also want the index of the minimum, you can use the `findmin` function. Unfortunately, this does not, for some reason, support a function argument, so you have to create a temporary array, and apply `findmin` to that:

```
julia> findmin(getfield.(fleet, :odometer))
(0.08468003971220694, 1)
```

You can also use `getproperty` instead of `getfield`, they do the same thing for your struct, I'm not certain which is preferable. Probably, the most idiomatic solution would be to define accessor functions instead of using the field values directly. For example:

```
odometer(car::Car) = car.odometer
minimum(odometer, fleet)
findmin(odometer.(fleet))
```

For maximum values, use `maximum` and `findmax`.

Comment: Perfect, the first two worked and solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Julia is about performance.

You should avoid using untyped `struct`s hence your type definition should be:

```
mutable struct Car
    load::Float64
    locale::Float64
    availability::Float64
    odometer::Float64
end
```

The code for creating `Vector` can be shorter:

```
cars = [Car(rand(4)...) for _ in 1:5]
```

The most efficient way to find the index of the minimum element is:

```
julia> Base.isless(c1::Car,c2::Car) = c1.odometer < c2.odometer

julia> findmin(cs)
(Car(0.7623514815463603, 0.7523019237133661, 0.37422766075278413, 0.49830949323733464), 3)
```